# exceptions in Launching Selendroid

Tags: java, android, selenium, android-testing, selendroid

Im trying to start with Selendroid testing. BUt when I'm Launching Selendroid with the following cammand:

```
java -jar selendroid-standalone-0.9.0-with-dependencies.jar -app selendroid-test-app-0.9.0.apk
```

Im getting exceptions as follows.

> D:\J Drive\android-sdk\tools>java -jar
>   selendroid-standalone-0.9.0-with-dependen
>                 cies.jar -app selendroid-test-app-0.9.0.apk
>                 Apr 01, 2014 5:44:02 PM io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher main
>                 INFO: ################# Selendroid #################
>                 Apr 01, 2014 5:44:02 PM io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher lauchServer
>                 INFO: Starting selendroid-server port 4444
>                 Apr 01, 2014 5:44:02 PM io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand exec
>                 INFO: executing command: D:\J Drive\android-sdk\build-tools\19.0.3\aapt.exe remo
>                 ve D:\J Drive\android-sdk\tools\selendroid-test-app-0.9.0.apk META-INF/MANIFEST.
>                 MF
>                 Apr 01, 2014 5:44:02 PM io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand exec
>                 INFO: executing command: D:\J Drive\android-sdk\build-tools\19.0.3\aapt.exe remo
>                 ve D:\J Drive\android-sdk\tools\selendroid-test-app-0.9.0.apk META-INF/CERT.RSA
>                 Apr 01, 2014 5:44:02 PM io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand exec
>                 INFO: executing command: D:\J Drive\android-sdk\build-tools\19.0.3\aapt.exe remo
>                 ve D:\J Drive\android-sdk\tools\selendroid-test-app-0.9.0.apk META-INF/CERT.SF
>                 Apr 01, 2014 5:44:02 PM io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand exec
>                 INFO: executing command: D:\J Drive\android-sdk\build-tools\19.0.3\aapt.exe remo
>                 ve D:\J Drive\android-sdk\tools\selendroid-test-app-0.9.0.apk META-INF/ANDROIDD.
>                 SF
>                 Apr 01, 2014 5:44:02 PM io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand exec
>                 INFO: executing command: D:\J Drive\android-sdk\build-tools\19.0.3\aapt.exe remo
>                 ve D:\J Drive\android-sdk\tools\selendroid-test-app-0.9.0.apk META-INF/ANDROIDD.
>                 RSA
>                 Apr 01, 2014 5:44:02 PM io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand exec
>                 INFO: executing command: J:\java\bin\jarsigner.exe -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg
>                  SHA1 -signedjar D:\J Drive\android-sdk\tools\resigned-selendroid-test-app-0.9.0
>                 .apk -storepass android -keystore C:\Users\ADMIN.android\debug.keystore D:\J Dr
>                 ive\android-sdk\tools\selendroid-test-app-0.9.0.apk androiddebugkey
>                 Apr 01, 2014 5:44:03 PM io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher lauchServer
>                 SEVERE: Error occurred while building server: An error occurred while resigning
>                 the app 'selendroid-test-app-0.9.0.apk'.
>                 io.selendroid.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: An error occurred while res
>                 igning the app 'selendroid-test-app-0.9.0.apk'.
>                     at io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.initApplication
>                 sUnderTest(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:114)
>                     at io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.(Selendro
>                 idStandaloneDriver.java:82)
>                     at io.selendroid.server.SelendroidStandaloneServer.initializeSelendroidS
>                 erver(SelendroidStandaloneServer.java:91)
>                     at io.selendroid.server.SelendroidStandaloneServer.(SelendroidStan
>                 daloneServer.java:65)
>                     at io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher.lauchServer(SelendroidLauncher.java:
>                 67)
>                     at io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher.main(SelendroidLauncher.java:114)
>                 Caused by: io.selendroid.exceptions.ShellCommandException: An error occured whil
>                 e executing shell command: J:\java\bin\jarsigner.exe -sigalg MD5withRSA -digesta
>                 lg SHA1 -signedjar D:\J Drive\android-sdk\tools\resigned-selendroid-test-app-0.9
>                 .0.apk -storepass android -keystore C:\Users\ADMIN.android\debug.keystore D:\J
>                 Drive\android-sdk\tools\selendroid-test-app-0.9.0.apk androiddebugkey
>                     at io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:53)
>                     at io.selendroid.builder.SelendroidServerBuilder.signTestServer(Selendro
>                 idServerBuilder.java:274)
>                     at io.selendroid.builder.SelendroidServerBuilder.resignApp(SelendroidSer
>                 verBuilder.java:134)
>                     at io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.initApplication
>                 sUnderTest(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:112)
>                     ... 5 more
>                 Caused by: io.selendroid.exceptions.ShellCommandException:
>                     ... 9 more
>                 Exception in thread "main" io.selendroid.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException:
>                 An error occurred while resigning the app 'selendroid-test-app-0.9.0.apk'.
>                     at io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.initApplication
>                 sUnderTest(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:114)
>                     at io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.(Selendro
>                 idStandaloneDriver.java:82)
>                     at io.selendroid.server.SelendroidStandaloneServer.initializeSelendroidS
>                 erver(SelendroidStandaloneServer.java:91)
>                     at io.selendroid.server.SelendroidStandaloneServer.(SelendroidStan
>                 daloneServer.java:65)
>                     at io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher.lauchServer(SelendroidLauncher.java:
>                 67)
>                     at io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher.main(SelendroidLauncher.java:114)
>                 Caused by: io.selendroid.exceptions.ShellCommandException: An error occured whil
>                 e executing shell command: J:\java\bin\jarsigner.exe -sigalg MD5withRSA -digesta
>                 lg SHA1 -signedjar D:\J Drive\android-sdk\tools\resigned-selendroid-test-app-0.9
>                 .0.apk -storepass android -keystore C:\Users\ADMIN.android\debug.keystore D:\J
>                 Drive\android-sdk\tools\selendroid-test-app-0.9.0.apk androiddebugkey
>                     at io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:53)
>                     at io.selendroid.builder.SelendroidServerBuilder.signTestServer(Selendro
>                 idServerBuilder.java:274)
>                     at io.selendroid.builder.SelendroidServerBuilder.resignApp(SelendroidSer
>                 verBuilder.java:134)
>                     at io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.initApplication
>                 sUnderTest(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:112)
>                     ... 5 more
>                 Caused by: io.selendroid.exceptions.ShellCommandException:
>                     ... 9 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank u I got the solution. In Environment Variable set "**ANDROID_HOME**" and "**PATH**"

```
Variable name :ANDROID_HOME 

variable value: D:\J Drive\android-sdk  (**"D:\J Drive\android-sdk"** is my android sdk path)

Variable name : PATH

variable value:D:\J Drive\android-sdk;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools
```

Comment: Setting environment variables didn't make a difference for me. Do you have any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Add to system environment key JAVA_HOME and value "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_39"